# Codename one Blue theme checkboxes in BoxLayout

Tags: checkbox, codenameone

I am using the CodenameOne blue theme ('shipped with' CodenameOne). I added checkboxes to a BoxLayout.Y container. When selecting one of the checkboxes, the checkbox is getting smaller and wider. I looked in the theme but I can't find out why.
Tested on Android 4.4

I added two images to show what happens. In the first, METAR was checked (and unchecked I guess), in the second, TAF was checked.

After checking another one, the size of the checkbox selected before is normal again.

[image: METAR was checked and unchecked and is smaller (height) and wider]

[image: TAF is checked and is smaller in height]

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 different state selected,unselected , pressed and disabled . And all styles of checkbox can be viewed in theme and as  the screenshot there is blank in pressed and disabled style so generate the styles from theme.

Comment: Just to add to this, copy the `CheckBox` styling under the `Unselected` section and paste it in `Selected` and `Pressed` sections.

Comment: Make sure the padding and margin are identical in the selected, unselected & pressed states. It should be the case for the theme out of the box so I'm not exactly sure what happened in this case.

Comment: I didn't change anything of this theme. I will try to copy the unselected states to all other states, but I already compared them and they seem exactly the same. Is it possible it has something to do with the BoxLayout they are in? Don't think so, but you'll never know.

Comment: Please delete other style except unselected one and then derived all one by one then it will work . Even though there is problem since post its  all styles screenshot so that we can detect the real problem